# How to set host url for springfox (more exact springfox-swagger2) in spring-mvc?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I have spring-mvc app and I've embed RestAPI in. All works correctly my rest api is mapped on `/rest/*` url. When I added SwaggerConfig it had started to recognise my controllers, but when I tried it out in swagger-ui (gui form to simplify consumers interaction with api) 
[image]

I've got 404 not found status. Because this tried it out on 
[image]
this doesnt do request on valid url

```
http://localhost:8080/ProductCatalog/rest/branch?id=1
```

although SwaggerConfig is mapped on correct url, because I've got this GUI representation when write

```
http://localhost:8080/ProductCatalog/rest/swagger-ui.html
```

There is a main part of app on root url (this isn't part in which i work) my part is mapped on `/rest/*`
How can I change this "try it out" url on `/rest/*` too?
My SwaggerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket pscApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                //.groupName("PSC");
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("restService.com.websystique.springmvc"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
        //PathSelectors.regex("/api/.*")
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("RestApiOfPSC")
                .description("REST API for PSC.")
                .build();
    }
}
```

and I've specified this too

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got how to do this.

```
docket.pathMapping("/rest");
```

and sometimes you need to change it another way
in your Docket bean write `docket.host("your host url");`
more exactly read my issue
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1468

and go through the reference #issue1050 too.